# lua: module import regarding local scope

Tags: module, lua, scope, embed, local

There are two script files with the following script

```
//parent.lua
function scope()
    local var = "abc"

    require "child"
end

//child.lua
print(var)
```

This way, child.lua will print a nil value because the scope in parent.lua does not expose its local features to the module. I thought it would, since the require directive is stated within this scope and after the declaration of var. My desire is to practically wholly inject all the lines of the child into the parent. The child script is just exported for better readability. How can I pass the local scope? loadfile() did not work, nor did dofile(). The function environment fenv does not harbor local values. debug.setlocal() does not seem to be able to create new variables (also it would require a receiver in the child). Any method besides recompiling the script?

Comment: No, this is not possible in Lua 5.1.  There is a hack that can give this effect in Lua 5.2, using `debug.upvaluejoin`.

Comment: Neither `require` nor `dofile` is the same as `include`, which does not exist in Lua.

Comment: Why don't you just rewrite your child script as a function receiving arguments?

Comment: @W.B. Doing this now. It's just complex and kind of ugly to transfer everything manually. A possibility would be to avoid the local keyword and instead put everything inside a table, then pass the table but you would need to index the table in the child and it slows things down. Furthermore, you cannot have direct pointers to primitives. In my scenario the parent and the child both need access to stuff like a number variable, so it either has to be global, part of a table or I have to provide functions for getting/setting its value, which again is not as performant.

Comment: Well, using require in a performance sensitive area is by far not the most efficient solution either. `require` first tries to index global with `package` table, which is then indexed with `loaded`, which is then indexed with your module name and depending on whether it's there or not, indexing may continue.

Comment: @user2399203 You are very likely trying to do something in a way that you should not. You should consider refactoring your scripts to fit better into a Lua environment instead of thinking in C or even PHP and then trying to hammer Lua into the square hole.

Answer (score 2):

You can with a bit of effort. If your variables in `child` are real upvalues you can "link" them to values in your `scope` function. If they are global variables (which seems to be the case here), you can map them to an environment using `setfenv` and populate that environment with values from your local variables.

The following will print `abc` as you'd expect (you can change `loadstring` to `loadfile` with the same effect):

```
function vars(f)
  local func = debug.getinfo(f, "f").func
  local i = 1
  local vars = {}
  while true do
    local name, value = debug.getlocal(f, i)
    if not name then break end
    if string.sub(name, 1, 1) ~= '(' then vars[name] = value end
    i = i + 1
  end
  i = 1
  while func do -- check for func as it may be nil for tail calls
    local name, value = debug.getupvalue(func, i)
    if not name then break end
    vars[name] = value
    i = i + 1
  end
  return vars
end

function parent()
  local var = "abc"

  local child = loadstring("print(var)")

  local env = vars(2) -- grab all local/upvalues for the current function
  -- use these values to populate new environment; map to _G for everything else
  setmetatable(env, {__index = _G})
  setfenv(child, env)

  child()
end

parent()
```

This is all for Lua 5.1, but it's also possible in Lua 5.2.