# dofile and require does not work as what i expected

Tags: lua

I want to load some lua file, and then paste it into middle of my code.

Like:

```
do
local abc = 123
dofile "somecode.lua"
end
```

And the somecode.lua file is:

```
if abc == 123
print("hello") end
```

What i expected progress and output from these codes&file:

```
do
local abc = 123
if abc == 123
print("hello") end
end

output: hello
```

But the real output displayed nothing because the 'local' declaration does not affect to the dofile function.

I wanna know way to insert a code into a middle of code that working as above(what i expected). there is any function that fits in my want?

Comment: Lua has lexical scoping. `dofile` is not the same as `#include`.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @lhf Thanks. so in Lua, there is no function that working like #include right? btw i found some similar questions. http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/scope-of-loadfile-dofile-require-td7595912.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715401/lua-module-import-regarding-local-scope

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there are some syntactical issues with your code.

`somecode.lua` must be

```
if abc == 123 then
print("hello")
end
```

Notice the `==` for comparison and `then` is introduced.

As for your problem, `hello` not being printed, the reason is that `abc` variable is declared `local`; therefore the `abc` variable used in the `if` statement is not referring to the local `abc` rather it is referring to default global `abc`. In order to fix this you must initialize a global `abc` in your file so that `somecode.lua` also picks up the same variable.

Something like this:

```
$ cat file1.lua 
do
abc = 123
dofile "somecode.lua"
end
$ cat somecode.lua 
if abc == 123 then
print("hello")
end
$ lua file1.lua 
hello
```

Comment: thanks for answer. um in my case, it need to stay in local declaration. the simple solution of my case is copy&paste the entire code between 'local abc = 123'...'end'. but really? there is no other way to insert file/text/code into a middle of code? i mean, there are many expedient ways to solve my problem. but i want to know is a fundamental way(if it exists)

Answer (score 0):

A Lua file is essentially a function. It can have a `return` statement, but it can't have parameters. To keep all variables local, `somecode.lua` should return a function.

`somecode.lua`:

```
return function(abc)
  if abc == 123 then
    print("hello")
  end
end
```

Other file:

```
dofile "somecode.lua"(123)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dofile you can use loadfile:

```
loadfile("some.lua","t",{abc=123,print=print})()
```

Here the table in the end is the environment.If you want the script to have the same environment then use that as the fallback environment. For Lua 5.2+ you would do:

```
do 
   loadfile("some.lua","t",setmetatable({abc=123},{__index=_ENV}))() 
end
```